# Magento CE 1.8.1 - duplicated newsletter subscription forms not posting

Tags: magento-1.8, template, newsletter

This is really puzzling me. I have 2 newsletter subscription forms on my site. On the home page, there is one at the top, below the banner, and the other is on every page located in the footer. I am also using the Ultimo theme from ThemeForest, and I had set the newsletter block from its default location in the footer like so in my `layout/local.xml`

```
<reference name="footer">
    <!-- Move newsletter to the footer -->
    <!--<block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" as="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>-->
    ....
</reference>
```

I then copied `/app/design/frontend/ultimo/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml` into my subtheme twice, calling one *subscribe_head.phtml* and the other *subscribe_footer.phtml*.

**subscribe_head.phtml**

```
<div id="subscribe-form-head" class="clearer">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-head-validate-detail">
        <div class="inner">
            <h5>Newsletter<span class="hide-c"> Signup</span></h5>
            <p>Sign up to get all the latest deals and earn 100 points</p>
            <div class="input-box">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" class="button btn-inline"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
            </div>            
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-head-validate-detail');
    new Varien.searchForm('newsletter-head-validate-detail', 'newsletter', '<?php echo $this->helper('newsletter')->__('Enter your email address') ?>');
//]]>
</script>
```

**subscribe_footer.phtml**

```
<div id="subscribe-form-footer" class="clearer">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-footer-validate-detail">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="input-box">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" class="button btn-inline"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></button>
                <input type="text" name="email2" id="newsletter-bottom" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
            </div>            
            <p>Catch up on all of the latest products and deals for the products you want! Sign up now and stay informed</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-footer-validate-detail');
    new Varien.searchForm('newsletter-footer-validate-detail', 'newsletter-bottom', '<?php echo $this->helper('newsletter')->__('Your email here...') ?>');
//]]>
</script>
```

Even though they look similar, you will see the layouts are slightly different, hence the template duplication. In static blocks, they are called as `{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe_head.phtml"}}` and `{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe_footer.phtml"}}` respectively.

***NOW***...`subscribe_head.phtml` works as it should - validation fires, and it posts fine. However, `subscribe_footer.phtml` does nothing. If left blank and the submit button is clicked, nothing happens, and I see a CSS class `validation-passed` being added to the input box in Chrome Inspector. Also, if I type any garbage into the box and submit the form, the page just posts back to itself with no error messages or notifications.

I've tried my best to keep both these templates unique, but nothing has worked out thus far for the footer form.

I really would appreciate any help with this. Many thanks!

---

**EDIT:** `subcribe_head` still works, and `subscribe_footer` now at least posts successfully. I found out that the Newsletter Signup controller requires the name `email` to be present in the POST variable. However, JavaScript validation does not seem to be firing on the `subscribe_footer` form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you now have most of it working other than the validation. I would imagine that for the validation to work on both forms you need "var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail" to be different on each form e.g

```
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetailHeader
```

&

```
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetailFooter
```

Comment: Hi James. Yes, I have done just this (same variable names in fact), but even this does not work. I looked through the controller to see if it was looking for anything specific, but this obviously was not the case.

Comment: Hi James. Any other thoughts on this?

Comment: You say "(same variable names in fact)" you set the 2 variables to have DIFFERENT names correct?

Comment: Hi James. By "same", I mean that I had set and spelt them exactly as you in your answer. So yes, they are different - `var newsletterSubscriberFormDetailHeader` and `var newsletterSubscriberFormDetailFooter`

Comment: Looks like it should be working, I copied your code (and updated email2 to email) into one of my own development sites and tested the validation on both forms and it worked perfectly. Perhaps you can share a live url?

Comment: ??? this is weird...it works for you but not for me. I'm still developing on localhost so nothing on a live server yet. I also changed `email2` to `email` as I realised that was the POST variable being used. Let me scrub everything and try again. If Im successful, I'll post back here

Comment: did you test this on a vanilla Magento install? Which version are you using?

Comment: On my local enterprise "playground"

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is that you are using the same JavaScript variable for both forms:

```
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-head-validate-detail');
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-footer-validate-detail');
```

Though it seems odd that the header works and not the footer, since I would suggest that it would take the form that is loaded last.

Comment: Hi David, and thank you for the suggestion. However neither this nor the solution from *programmer_rkt* above seems to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe_head.phtml"}}
 {{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe_head.phtml"}}
```

You should have a `name` property for block definition. This is how magento uniquely identifies your block. Most probably this may cause the problem.

So try this in your static blocks

```
 {{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="top.newsletter"  template="newsletter/subscribe_head.phtml"}}
 {{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="bottom.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe_head.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply, however this does not seem to have any effect.